# Angular 5 - how to make the period field type lowercase in DatePipe

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-pipe, angular-date-format

Using DatePipe in Angular 5.1, I need to format the period field type (AM/PM) in lowercase. According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe),

```
Tuesday, December 19, 7:00 am
```

should be

```
date:'EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm a'
```

However, the period field type always displays in uppercase, so I see this:

```
Tuesday, December 19, 7:00 AM
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known defect wtih Angular's date formatting?

Comment: Split it up.  - {1234567 l date:'EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm '} {1234567 l date:' a'  l lowercase } I have not tried it but should logically work.

Comment: please see my updated answer how to achieve it with `date` pipe only

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just split your date to 2 parts:

```html
{{ today | date : 'EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm' }} {{ today | date : 'a' | lowercase }}
```

...............

**UPDATE**

Here is another simple way to achieve it, using built in `date` pipe and [*aaaaa* matcher](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/i18n/format_date.ts#L473) (which returns lowercase `a` or `p`):

```js
<div>{{ today | date : 'EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm aaaaa\'m\'' }}</div>
```

Updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcpgzb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

...............

**ANGULAR JS solution**

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $locale) {
  $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.AMPMS = ['am', 'pm'];
  $scope.today = new Date();
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/a49kjvOdifXPAvBlmXEi?p=preview

Comment: I have just noticed, that @Gary answered exactly the same in the comment, sorry

Comment: Perfect! Much cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Bummer. This is still the case with Angular 5.

I've created a custom pipe which applies a lowercase transform to the text matching a provided regex.

#### Lowercase Match Pipe

**lowercase-match.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform  } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'lowercaseMatch'
})
export class LowerCaseMatchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform (input: any, pattern: any): any {

    if (!this.isString(input)) {
      return input;
    }

    const regexp = pattern instanceof RegExp ? pattern : new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');

    return input.toLowerCase()
    if (input.match(regexp)) {
      return input.toLowerCase()
    }

    return input
  }

  isString(value: any): boolean {
    return typeof value === 'string';
  }
}
```

#### Usage

**Import to Module**

```js
import { LowerCaseMatchPipe } from './lowercase-match.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    LowerCaseMatchPipe
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Display date with lowercase am/pm**

```js
{{ today | date : 'EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm a' | lowercaseMatch : 'am|pm' }}
```

---

*There is some discussion about this casing notion on an GitHub Issue for Angular
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8763*

Comment: Looks like they won't implement it any time soon, there was a pull request to add lowercase am/pm and it was closed with [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8830#issuecomment-139993165)

Comment: Basically Angular defines it's date/time symbols from the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR). And.... 

*"The CLDR is very extensive, it does not cover every use case. Eg it does not cover lower case version of the time period (ie, am/pm). It would be close to impossible for an independent library to add and maintain a symbol that is not in the CLDR, as the amount of work would be overwhelming and the benefit would be very limited."

I would recommend you that you just add the filter lowercase to the expression to work around this limitation."*

Answer (score 1):

I want to add onto Andriy's response and combine it into a single interpolation

```
{{ (today | date: 'MMM d, y, h:mm') + (today | date: 'a' | lowercase) }}
```

I was having an issue where a space was being added between the two interpolations of Andriy's proposal. That can work if that's what you want, but I needed lowercase with no space:
ex. Oct 21, 2020, 1:16pm

Answer (score 1):

The form that would best be presented would be:

{{ today | date: 'MMM d, y, h:mm' | titlecase }}