# how to convert date format into lowercase

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a custom Date and I am trying to format it using | date: 'dd LLLL yyyy hh:mm aa' pipe so the result is - 30 August 2022 12:00 PM, but I want this date in 30 August 2022 12:00 pm/am formate how can I do that,

```
<ng-container *ngIf="date else empty">
  {{date | date: 'dd LLLL yyyy hh:mm aa'}}
</ng-container>
```

result - 30 August 2022 12:00 PM

expectation - 30 August 2022 12:00 pm

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880699/angular-5-how-to-make-the-period-field-type-lowercase-in-datepipe

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8763

Answer (score 0):

It should do the work :

```
let date = '30 August 2022 12:00 PM'.split(' ');
let end = date.pop().toLowerCase();
let result = [...date, end].join(' ');
console.log(result);
// Output
// 30 August 2022 12:00 pm
```